# Why do the fields of the last pushed back object into a vector transfer to the other objects of the vector?

Tags: c++, vector, deep-copy, shallow-copy, imgui

I am a little bit stuck with my code and I am not being able to find out the problem. I hope you can help me.

I have 4 Classes:
- class BasicModul: it has, among others, one field called modulName.
- class DrawingSettings: not relevant at this point
- class ModulRepresentation: constructed with a BasicModul object and a DrawingSettings object.
- class ModulesContainer: it has a field which is a std::vector  . Its object used in the code is "container".

My problem is that apparently when pushing back a new ModulRepresentation into the ModulesContainer (a vector of ModulRepresentation), it seems that the fields of the last ModulRepresentation created and pushed back are passed into the fields of the previously created and pushed back ModulRepresentation in the ModulContainer. The ModulContainer "container" is initialized at the beginning of the code. I am using ImGui for creating the GUI.

Where is the mistake? I had previously a simpler code that was doing basically the same but less encapsulated (so, for example, the std::vector was directly defined in the main code and so on) and it worked as expected. The modulCounter variable starts with value 0. I think the names of the functions of the classes should be descriptive enough, but if you need more information please just let me know.

Thanks in advance!

```
            if (ImGui::Button("MODUL")){                // Buttons return true when clicked
                modulCounter++;

                int auxiliar=modulCounter*10;

                std::string saux = std::to_string(auxiliar);

                std::cout << "Here 1" << std::endl;         

                BasicModul modAux(saux);
                ModulDrawingSettings modDrawSet;
                ModulRepresentation modRep(modAux, modDrawSet);

                container.push_backModul(modRep);   

                std::cout << saux << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Vector Size/Capacity: " << container.modulesContainerSize() <<  "/" << container.modulesContainerCapacity() << std::endl;


                std::cout << "Here 2" << std::endl;


                for (int j=0; j<container.modulesContainerSize(); j++){

                    BasicModul modAuxiliar = container.getModulRepresentation(j).getBasicModul();

                    std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "Position in the container" << j << std::endl;
                    std::cout << container.getPointerToModulRepresentation(j) << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "name of the modul" << container.getModulRepresentation(j).getBasicModul().getModulName() << std::endl;

                }

                std::cout << "Here 3" << std::endl;
```

And here is the output:

```
Here 1
Address of the original modul object: 0x7ffd6ba4cf30
10
Vector Size/Capacity: 1/1
name of the last modul passed: 10
Here 2


Position in the container0
0x5595967583c0
name of the modul10
Here 3
Here 1
Address of the original modul object: 0x7ffd6ba4cf30
20
Vector Size/Capacity: 2/2
name of the last modul passed: 20
Here 2


Position in the container0
0x559596b4c600
name of the modul20


Position in the container1
0x559596b4c720
name of the modul20
Here 3
Here 1
Address of the original modul object: 0x7ffd6ba4cf30
30
Vector Size/Capacity: 3/4
name of the last modul passed: 30
Here 2


Position in the container0
0x559596bb99b0
name of the modul30


Position in the container1
0x559596bb9ad0
name of the modul30


Position in the container2
0x559596bb9bf0
name of the modul30
Here 3
Here 1
Address of the original modul object: 0x7ffd6ba4cf30
40
Vector Size/Capacity: 4/4
name of the last modul passed: 40
Here 2


Position in the container0
0x559596bb99b0
name of the modul40


Position in the container1
0x559596bb9ad0
name of the modul40


Position in the container2
0x559596bb9bf0
name of the modul40


Position in the container3
0x559596bb9d10
name of the modul40
Here 3
```

Comment: Learn about deep vs shallow copy.

Comment: The bug is in one or more of the involved classes, where you don't copy as much as you should.

Comment: @stark thank you for your answer. I have learnt about those concepts (deep vs shallow copy), and although I think I see which kind of problem you have in mind, I am not being able to reproduce it in a simpler example I created. Could you please explain a little bit more what you mean? Do you think I need a non-default copy constructor, although I am not dealing with dynamically alocated elements and pointers? I edited a little bit the output information to include something else, I think it could be helpful.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: either `BasicModul`, `ModulDrawingSettings`, or `ModulRepresentation` , or other classes they have as members, contains pointer or reference members or an incorrect user-defined copy/move constructor or assignment operators

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Thank you for your responses! It just came to my mind where I think the error could be. As you say, there is actually one field, the name, which is char const *, therefore I will need a deep copy there to overcome it. Actually I did modify the classes for removing all the other pointers, since the initial objects go out of scope  after this part of the code. I will fix this and let you know if it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I found out finally the error. As @stark and later @M.M suggested,the problem was a field being a pointer, and therefore pointing all the time to the same address which was updated with the last pushed back object in the vector. Since it was a pointer, the shallow copy (which takes place during the push back into the vector) is not enough. I fixed it just by making that field just a "normal" type as I intended initially, and not a pointer.

Thank you for your answers!